# Can't dynamically bind __repr__/__str__ to a class created with type

Tags: python, types

I'm rolling my own `Enum` class for python and I'm having trouble getting `__str__` and `__repr__` to work correctly, what am I doing wrong?

```
In [2]: x = Enum(X=1, Y=2)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: common.utils.Enum

In [4]: str(x)
Out[4]: "<class 'common.utils.Enum'>"

In [5]: x.__repr__
Out[5]: <bound method type.reprfun of <class 'common.utils.Enum'>>

In [6]: x.__repr__()
Out[6]: 'Enum(Y=2, X=1)'
```

The code itself:

```
def Enum(*args, **kwargs):
    enums = dict(zip(args, range(len(args))), **kwargs)
    def reprfun(self):
        res = 'Enum(' +\
            ', '.join(map(lambda x: '{}={}'.format(x[0],x[1]), enums.items())) +\
            ')'
        return res

    reverse = dict((value, name) for name, value in enums.items())
    typedict = enums.copy()
    typedict['name'] = reverse
    instance = type('Enum', (), typedict)
    instance.__repr__ = types.MethodType(reprfun, instance)
    instance.__str__ = types.MethodType(reprfun, instance)
    return instance
```

Comment: You should bind `__repr__` to the class, not to the instance.

Comment: are you using the builtin Enum (http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html), a back port of this or  a different implementation? - nm - i see you are rolling your own. you should look at the implementation of the actual enum class in the python source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Special methods must be added to the class, not to the instance. Any special method is always looked up on the type.

If Python didn't work like that, you couldn't use `repr(ClassObj)` as that'd call the `ClassObj.__repr__` method which would expect `self` as a first argument. So Python calls `type(obj).__repr__(obj)` instead.

From the [datamodel documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes):

> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.
>
> [...]
>
> The rationale behind this behaviour lies with a number of special methods such as **hash**() and **repr**() that are implemented by all objects, including type objects. If the implicit lookup of these methods used the conventional lookup process, they would fail when invoked on the type object itself:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> 1 .__hash__() == hash(1)
> True
> >>> int.__hash__() == hash(int)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: descriptor '__hash__' of 'int' object needs an argument
> ```

The following works:

```
typedict = enums.copy()
typedict.update({
    'name': reverse,
    '__repr__': reprfun,
    '__str__': reprfun,
})

instance = type('Enum', (), typedict)
return instance
```

You do want to be careful with the naming though; `instance` is bound to a **class object** here, not an instance. The name is thus misleading. You may want to use `cls` or `classobj` or similar instead of `instance`.

Demo:

```
>>> x = Enum(X=1, Y=2)
>>> x
<class '__main__.Enum'>
>>> x.__repr__
<unbound method Enum.reprfun>
>>> x()
Enum(Y=2, X=1)
>>> str(x())
'Enum(Y=2, X=1)'
>>> repr(x())
'Enum(Y=2, X=1)'
```

Comment: I tried what you propose and still doesn't work, repr is not calling the function I provided.

Comment: @piotr: I tested and it does work. Are you certain you are creating an *instance* of the class you return?

Comment: so what I was calling instance was the class type. Thanks a lot, can you maybe edit your answer so it's less misleading.

Comment: @piotr: It's your own naming of the type as `instance` that is misleading here. :-) I already stated that in my answer.